# Inverse Laplace transform and convolution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution

Suppose we have two functions of $t$, $f(t)$ and $g(t)$.

Letting $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = F(s)$ and $\mathcal{L}\{g(t)\} = G(s)$, I know that:

$$\mathcal{L}\{f(t) \star g(t)\} = F(s) \cdot G(s),$$

but then I thought naturally it should be true that, applying the inverse Laplace transform to both sides, we get:

$$f(t) \star g(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{ F(s) \cdot G(s) \}.$$

However, this appears to be not the case, or at least for the question:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{ \frac{1}{s^2} \cdot \frac{1}{s-3} \right\},$$

where I would have expected the answer to be:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ \frac{1}{s^2} \cdot \frac{1}{s-3} \right\} = t \star e^{3t}.$$

However this is not the case. I do not understand why, however. Is my issue that I am assuming $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\mathcal{L}\{h(t)\}\} = h(t)$? Or is it deeper than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
t*e^{3t}=\int_0^t (t-\tau)e^{3\tau}\,d\tau=\frac{1}{9}(e^{3t}-1-3t)
$$
and that seems to be the same one gets doing partial fraction decomposition on $1/(s^2(s-3))$,
$$
\frac{1}{s^2(s-3)}=\frac{1}{9}\Bigl(\frac{1}{s-3}-\frac{3}{s^2}-\frac{1}{s}\Bigr),
$$
and then inverse Laplace transform, yielding $\frac{1}{9}(e^{3t}-1-3t)$ again.

So, everything seems to be OK.

Comment: I guess it necessary (or good form) to take that extra step to remove the convolution operator. Thank you.